# facebook social plugin for website

Tags: web-applications, facebook-social-plugins

I would like to know which social plugin they are using on a site, as I want to add the same plugin for a customer on their website.  The site is smithandwillis.com, and the plugin is on the left side, close to the bottom.

I have looked at the plug ins, and none seem  exactly like this one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

With show faces off, and show stream on

Answer (score 0):

Can you please let us know the website technology for which you are looking for a plugin? You can check many 3rd party vendors like loginradius, janrain, gigya as they provide already built plugins for many cms and sdks for core technology